# 3rd party HDDs in Dell Poweredge r805

Tags: hardware-raid, sata, dell-perc

I have a Dell Poweregde R805 Server that came with two 147GB 10K SAS drives. To stack up the storage on this machine, i purchased two SATA drives (HGST Travelstar Z7K500, 500GB, 7200RPM, SATA III). The RAID controller is a PERC 6/i. The new drives seem to work fine in an initialized RAID 1 but they are both flagged as faulty. I woundn't know if one of the drives fails because of this error. I am using VMware ESXi 6.0 and the error reads: "DriveFault - Assert"

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that warnings about non-validated drives should actually mark a drive as failed/faulty. You may consider updating the firmware on that card if you aren't already on the latest revision, and ensuring that you're using a driver on VMware's HCL for that card.